# MongoDB custom discriminator for Array

Tags: .net, arrays, mongodb, serialization, discriminator

I'm using MongoDB (.NET driver 1.10) to store my C# class which has a weak-typed field:

```
public class SomeClass : ...
{
    ...

    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

By default if Value contains an array the class is serialized to the document with very long discriminator:

```
{
    ...

    "Value" : {
        "_t" : "SomeSolution.Domain.SomeSubdomain.SomeFolder.SomeSubfolder.SpecialValueClass[], SomeSolution.Domain",
        "_v" : [ 
            {
                ...
            }, 
            {
                ...
            }, 
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

But I want to use just "SpecialValueClass[]" discriminator string (or shorter).

I tried to configure mapping like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<SpecialValueClass>();
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<SpecialValueClass[]>(
            cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.SetDiscriminator("SpecialValueClass[]");
            });
```

This has no effect for array types, generic lists (but works for solutuion-defined types).

How can I tell mongodb driver to use custom discriminator for my array type? I prefer using no wrapper classes, nor serialization attributes. Or why my configuration is ignored by the driver?

Comment: Why do you care honestly?

Comment: Because the discriminator field size is bigger than all other data fields size almost always.

Comment: and how is that a problem?

Comment: This collection is 95% of my db. Reducing the discriminator size will greatly reduce the total db size.